# Migrate views in drupal 7 easily - D7

Tags: drupal-7, migration

I want to migrate all views from my local site to another site. 
I know there is a module "Migrate" which allows you to do data migration but I don't know how to use it.

Can you give me some tips?

Thanks in advancej

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean with migrating views to another site. In Drupal, the migration concept is usually associated with actually migrating data - a view is actually just a way to query and display this data.

Typically *moving* a view to a different site, assuming data structures are the same in both can be accomplished by either exporting the view (one of the options while browsing the views on admin/structure/views) or, if it's not just a one of, by featurizing it which is a process that takes a few more steps.

Answer (score 1):

**It's only applicable for drupal site to drupal site**

First download [features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module and enabled in both sites.
Go to **admin-structure > features > create feature**.

In that you can see **General information**(left side) and **Components**(right side). The General information provide some name in the name fields and you can see **views** in Components. You just select what are all views are needed for that site.Click the **Download feature** button.

It will downloaded!!!

After that copy the downloaded file to new drupal site which has **drupalroot > sites > modules**.

Go to your "**new drupal site**" as (**Admin-Structure > feature**). You can see the folder name as list in that. Enable the folder name list and click "**Save settings**". After the save setting finished as good then deselect the folder list, click "**save settings**" and **delete** the downloaded folder in module folder.

Note: 
The folder name list should not **state** as **conflict**. If it presents, then click the recreate button.